# Importing packages created Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-os

I have folder structure like below:

TEST-
A-
a1.py
a2.py
B-
b1.py
C-
myscript.py

So, how can i import myscript.py in a1.py script without manually setting current working directory in a1, a2 and b1 scripts

Comment: can you be clearer in the structure of the scripts? I can't understand where the parent folder is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to want to have a folder structure like shown below,

```
project
│
├───A
│       a1.py
│       a2.py
├───B
│       b.py
├───C
│   │   my_script.py
```

And you want to import functions or classes from my_script.py to some other file.

To do that you have to add **init**.py file to folders. Your folder structure will look like this after doing that.

```
project
|
│   __init__.py
│
├───A
│       a1.py
│       a2.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───B
│       b.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───C
│   │   my_script.py
│   │   __init__.py
```

You can import my_script like this in any of the folders above,

```
from project import my_script
```